# How to include a file from a folder in htdocs in PHP?

Tags: php, directory

Ive looked everywhere but cant find anything.
I have a few php folders in a folder in htdocs. Heres the layout:

```
    htdocs(root folder)>widget_corp>
                                    public>(php file i need to include header.php in)
                                    includes>layouts>header.php
```

I have tried to include header.php in the php file in public but using the `include` statement but it hasnt worked. What should i put in my inlcude statement to include the header.php?

Comment: Can you document a bit better what the folder layout looks like?

Comment: @Jek how? Public and includes are both folders inside widget_corp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your folder structure is the following:

```
public -> example.php
includes -> layouts -> header.php
```

When opening `example.php`, you can use the code:

```
include "../includes/layours/header.php";
```

And that will include the PHP `header.php` file into your `example.php` file.

**Note:** The `../` means going to the Parent Directory, and the `./` means current directory, just wanted to add that for you in the future.

Comment: Yes that was it! I forgot to add the ".." before the /. Thank you.